# Cannot convert value of type '<[AnyObject]>'to type 'NSArray' in coercion

Tags: swift

I can't get my head around this. I've tried different variants of casting but can't seem to get it.

```
    var tArray : NSArray = tempArr2 as NSArray
    memoArray = tArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Full error message is:

*Cannot convert value of type 'ReverseRandomAccessCollection<[AnyObject]>' (aka 'ReverseRandomAccessCollection>') to type 'NSArray' in coercion*

Here's the entire block although I don't think it will make a difference because the error is only with this casting method.

```
    var tempArr : Array = memoArray as Array
    print("beforeReverse=\(tempArr)")
    var tempArr2 = tempArr.reverse()
    print("afterReverse=\(tempArr2)")
    var tArray : NSArray = tempArr2 as NSArray // <----- error
    memoArray = tArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

    memoArray.addObject(memoDictionary)

    tempArr  = memoArray as Array
    print("beforeReverse=\(tempArr)")
    tempArr2 = tempArr.reverse()
    print("afterReverse=\(tempArr2)")
    tArray  = tempArr2 as NSArray // <----- error
    memoArray = tArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `reverse()` return type. You should cast it to `Array`:

```
var tempArr2 = Array(tempArr.reverse())
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. I knew it was simple like that. I've been on the same scene for 12 hours. I guess it pays to take breaks and pay more attention. You are my God for today :)

Comment: @TokyoToo Next time you'll pay more attention for type casting =)